# Selecting decimal values with scale > X

Tags: sql, oracle, precision

Given a column defined as `NUMBER(18,5)`, select all values that has more than `X` explicit decimal places, eg.:

```
1.00001
1.00012
1.00123
1.01234
1.12345
1.12340 (1.1234)
1.12300 (1.123)
1.12000 (1.12)
1.10000 (1.1)
```

When `X = 4`, we'll have:

```
1.00001
1.00012
1.00123
1.01234
1.12345
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical solution is to raise the number to the target power of 10, and then check if there is a decimal reminder.

So the condition would look like:

```
trunc(:mynumber * power(10, :myscale)) <> :mynumber * power(10, :myscale)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f26b13217e1e22a3d10ab1bad2332872)**:

```
with mynumbers as (
    select 1.00001 num from dual
    union all select 1.00012 from dual
    union all select 1.00123 from dual
    union all select 1.01234 from dual
    union all select 1.12345 from dual
    union all select 1.12340 from dual
    union all select 1.12300 from dual
    union all select 1.12000 from dual
    union all select 1.10000 from dual
),
    myscale as (select 4 sca from dual)
select *
from mynumbers n
inner join myscale s
    on trunc(n.num * power(10, s.sca)) <> n.num * power(10, s.sca)
```

```
    NUM | SCA
------: | --:
1.00001 |   4
1.00012 |   4
1.00123 |   4
1.01234 |   4
1.12345 |   4
```

Comment: Excuse me, but why power of 10?

Comment: 4 power 10 means 10000. So basically, multiply the number by 1000, and see if there is a decimal reminder.

Comment: @GMB I posted an alternate answer you might be interested in.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of GMB's answer (which I like so I've also upvoted).  You can check for the decimal component using `mod()`:

```
mod(n.num * power(10, s.sca), 1) <> 0
```

The argument `1` takes the fraction component.

Answer (score 1):

A little simpler than GMB's answer, which I've upvoted and is good, is to just compare the number to the `trunc()` of the number at the desired precision.

E.g., if you want everything with at least 4 decimal places of precision,

```
WHERE num != trunc(num,4-1);
```

Take a number like 0.1234.  `trunc(0.1234,4-1)` is 0.123, which is different from the number and a giveaway that the number had at least 4 decimal places.

Comment: This looks like the neatest option!

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server this should work :

WHERE LEN(CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION,[your_column]))-(LEN(CONVERT(INT,[your_column]))+1) > 4

Comment: Are you sure this is an oracle solution? The [`CONVERT` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm#SQLRF00620) is for changing character sets on strings.

Comment: And there’s no `len()` function in Oracle.

Comment: My bad it's for SQL servers did not noticed it was for an Oracle database.